# (Union of arbitrary family of sets)° is not equal to union of interior of sets

Tags: general-topology

I want a counter example that why is interior of union of arbitrary family of sets not a subset of union of arbitrary family of interior sets

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^c$.

or

$(1,2]$ and $[2,3]$.

For infinite case let the rests be nulls.

Comment: But here are only two sets.

Comment: How many do you want, you said **arbitrary family**

Comment: What if arbitrarily many intervals are to be used?

Comment: @VikasSharma Added, check it

Answer (score 0):

In  ${\mathbb{R}}$

Let $S_x = {x}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Interior of any S is empty set

Interior of union is ${\mathbb{R}}$